# Conditional \bye?

Tags: input, plain-tex

Editing  a huge document is painfully slow. So one splits it into pieces and has a main document that does `\input this` and `\input that`. **But:** While I'm editing `this.tex` I want a `\bye` at the end to make a preview work right, but if the file ends with `\bye` the compilation of the master document stops after `\input this`.

There must be a standard solution; the title is conjecturing maybe there's a way to say "`\bye`, unless this file is being inputted"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution might be to define a custom `\bye` command, for example `\mybye`, in the main document. In the subdocument you can perform a check if this command is defined, if not then you define it to be `\bye`. The definition in the main document can be empty.

Checking if a command exists can be done with `\ifcsname` (which is an e-TeX macro).

MWE, main document:

```
Hello from master document\par
\def\mybye{}
\input subdocument
more text in master document
\bye
```

subdocument:

```
\ifcsname mybye\endcsname\else\def\mybye{\csname bye\endcsname}\fi
Hello from subdocument\par
\mybye
```

Comment: Thx. I have the impression I understand how that works - spooky...

Comment: Surely the command should have been called `\maybye`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a macro only defined in the main file.

#### file dcu.tex

```
\def\ABCDEFGHIJK{}

\input dcu1

\input dcu2

\bye
```

#### File `dcu1.tex`

```
This is the first file

\ifx\ABCDEFGHIJK\undefined\csname bye\expandafter\endcsname\fi
```

#### File `dcu2.tex`

```
This is the second file

\ifx\ABCDEFGHIJK\undefined\csname bye\expandafter\endcsname\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latex, you can use `expl3` to define a `boolean` `\l_bye_bool` (initially set to false) to judge if an input should be done.

- `\bye` set `\l_bye_bool` to true
- `\myinput` judge whether to input a file according to `\l_bye_bool`

Then if `a1.tex` contains a `\bye`, following `\myinput` will do nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_bye_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \l_bye_bool
\cs_new_protected:Nn \l_bye_cs: {\bool_gset_true:N \l_bye_bool}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \l_input_cs:n {
  \if_bool:N \l_bye_bool {}
  \else: {\input{#1}}
  \fi:
}
\NewDocumentCommand {\bye} { } {\l_bye_cs:}
\NewDocumentCommand {\myinput} { m } {\l_input_cs:n {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\myinput{a1.tex}

\myinput{a2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code `\if_bool:N \l_bye_bool {} \else: {\input{#1}} \fi:` inputs the file in a group, which is not necessarily bad, but it's better to avoid. I'd suggest using the branching conditional version: `\bool_if:NTF \l_bye_bool { } { \input {#1} }`. Also you use `\bool_gset_(true|false):N` in a local variable. You should rename `\l_bye_bool` to `\g_bye_bool`.

Comment: Thanks very much to point out